# Will returned object be accessible after function ends execution?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, scope

I already have `XXX` struct and `getXXX()` function.
Now i need function to access `yyy` field of `XXX` struct.

```
typedef struct _XXX_ {
    //--other data
    char yyy[MAX_YYY_LEN];
} XXX;

XXX *getXXX(void);

const char* myFoo(void){
    XXX *ptrToXXX;
    ptrToXXX = getXXX();
    return ptrToXXX->yyy;
}
```

I have two questions:
Will data returned by `myFoo()` be accessible after function termination, or it may point to nowhere, cause out of scope?
Do i need to destruct `ptrToXXX` ? I mean, if i call `myFoo()` 1000000 times - will it allocate a lot of memory for `XXX *` pointers?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the implementation of `XXX *getXXX(void);`?

Comment: Implementation of `getXXX()` is unknown (i have only header and lib), but it will return pointer to one and only one object, that exists for sure and will exist "forever".

Comment: Well, memory for the pointer will be allocated on the stack every time you call that function. The object will stay the same if there's only one object (e.g. a `static` declared inside `getXXX()`).

Comment: I'm sorry to pester, but memory, that allocated on the stack every time i call that function - is it need to be deallocated?

Comment: No, the stack is balanced automatically.

Comment: As long as the XXX object ptrToXXX is pointing to is guaranteed to be valid by the getXXX() implementation - as you commented already - (and yyy being public...), everything is fine with your function. ptrToXXX is nothing more than a variable on the stack, which is cleaned up automatically, as Panta Rei said already. Counter-example: Imagine getXXX() would return a new object (`new XXX()`) every time you call it. ptrToXXX would still be cleaned up, but not the XXX object it pointed to --> memory leak! If you then `delete ptrToXXX;` before returning, you return a pointer to invalid memory...